# Reponsive Grid Layout with MUI in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

I'm working with the grid system from MUI for the first time and I don't quite know what I'm doing.

I need a vertical grid, which is responsive. I attach an example image.

Here is my example, where I tried to use the default component from MUI. Maybe somebody can help me find a better way to work with this grid.

```
    <Grid
  container
  spacing={2}
  sx={{
    height: '100vh',
    background: '#f2f2f2',
  }}
>
  <Grid
    item
    xs={12}
    md={4}
    sx={{ height: '100%' }}
    justifyContent={'center'}
    justifySelf={'center'}
    justifyItems={'center'}
  >
    <LogoComponent></LogoComponent>
    <InfoBoxComponent
      id={''}
      base={''}
      link={''}
      accumulation={''}
    ></InfoBoxComponent>
    <ProfileComponent
      username={'test'}
      avatar={''}
      tokens={'12000'}
    ></ProfileComponent>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={4} sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
    <MenuComponent
      items={[
        {
          value: 'test',
          label: 'test',
        },
        {
          value: 'test',
          label: 'test',
        },
        {
          value: 'test',
          label: 'test',
        },
        {
          value: 'test',
          label: 'test',
        },
      ]}
    ></MenuComponent>
    <img src={'../assets/items/avatar.png'} alt="Logo" width={700} />;
    <ButtonComponent
      text={'Test'}
      variant={'contained'}
      size={'large'}
    ></ButtonComponent>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={4} sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
    <WardrobeComponent title={'title'} amount={2}></WardrobeComponent>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: I added it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use Grid container direction `column`. Something like this:

```
<Grid container spacing={2} justify="center">
  <Grid item container direction="column" xs={8} sm={2} spacing={2}>
    <Grid item>
      <Paper style={{ height: "31vh", background: "orange" }} />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
      <Paper style={{ height: "31vh", background: "green" }} />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
      <Paper style={{ height: "31vh", background: "blue" }} />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item container direction="column" xs={8} sm={2} spacing={2}>
    <Grid item>
      <Paper style={{ height: "31vh", background: "red" }} />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
      <Paper style={{ height: "31vh", background: "yellow" }} />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
      <Paper style={{ height: "31vh", background: "purple" }} />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
    <Paper style={{ height: "97vh", background: "lightgrey" }} />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[Working Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-grid-demo-forked-17f4gk).